# Adding a conditional redirect with Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: silverlight, redirect, wif

My silverlight project, Relaying Party (RP), uses WIF with passive authentication to control access.  I need to add the ability to add a redirect to the login path.

When someone tries to access a page, they are redirected to the IP-STS to authenticate.  Once Authenticated I want display a License agreement.  Once the user hits ok, they would be redirected to the original page.

The path would be:

any site within the RP => IP-STS => License agreement => original Site

If it is easier, it would also be acceptible to display the agreement before going to STS, such as:

any site within the RP => License agreement => IP-STS => original Site

Ultimately, I want to set a cookie on the License agreement so that once it is accepted the user wouldn't have to see the license agreement anymore.

Does anyone have advice on this?

Comment: Is License agreement inside Silverlight app or is it on separate web page? Do You host your Silv app on Web Forms page or on MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including these two parts in the config file ended up working once I configured the Terms.aspx page correctly with the FederatedPassiveSignIn object on the Terms.aspx page.

In the configuration tag:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Terms.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

In the system.web tag:

```
<location path="Terms.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```